# How to set cell language for good number formatting in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, openoffice-calc

I try to set polish currency format in xslx file using openpyxl.

I have:

```py
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('myFile.xlsx')
    sheet = xfile.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.utf8')
getcontext().prec = 3 #decimal precission

sheet[f'E1'].number_format = '# ##0,00 [$zł-415];-# ##0,00 [$zł-415]'
sheet[f'E1'] = Decimal(PRICENET) #PRICENET is 17.8
```

So, when I open this file in OpenOffice Calc and I check cell format I see that cell is Currency with good polish currency format but the language is "Default - English (USA)". The cell display "018 zł". When I change the cell language to "Polish" in the cell is "17,80 zł" so it's preferred. What's the clue?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, local settings are global for the application and not for workbooks or worksheets (you cannot set the language for cells) so that even if you set the currency as you have, the settings in the application will take precedence.